# Save SSRS data source as .ds file programmatically

Tags: c#, reporting-services, xml-serialization

I have a web service to an SSRS server from which I download and serialize reports to XML in C#, and then later save as `.rdl` files.

I have the possibility to get the all the `Data Source`'s aswell, with

```
ReportingService2005 rs = new ReportingService2005();
DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
DataSourceDefinition dataSourceDefinition = rs.GetDataSourceContents(path);
dataSource.Item = dataSourceDefinition;
```

I want to save the `data source` objects as `.ds` or `.rds` files but I don't know how. Is there a way I can do this using XML serializing or are there any easier methods?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just grabbing this all out of the ReportServer.dbo.Catalog table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kyzen suggested in the comment, I used a combination of some custom code and this post from SO [Listing all Data Sources and their Dependencies (reports, items, etc) in SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638431/listing-all-data-sources-and-their-dependencies-reports-items-etc-in-sql-ser) to get the result I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I used the XML serialize to serialize the DataSource object here is the code snipet:

```
DataSource ds = new DataSource();
                    DataSourceDefinition dsDefinition = rs.GetDataSourceContents(item.Path);
                    ds.Item = dsDefinition;
                    sOutFile = string.Format(@"{0}{1}.rds", sOutputDir, item.Name);
                    if (File.Exists(sOutFile))
                        File.Delete(sOutFile);
                    SerializeObject(sOutFile, ds);   // serializes the dataSource object and save it
```

here is the SerializeObject method, it serializes and then saves the file in XML format:

```
private void SerializeObject(string filename, DataSource d)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer =
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSource));
            // Create an XmlTextWriter using a FileStream.
            Stream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
            XmlWriter writer =
            new XmlTextWriter(fs, Encoding.Unicode);
            // Serialize using the XmlTextWriter.
            serializer.Serialize(writer, d);
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show("inside serializeObject Method "+e.Message); }
    }
```

I hope this helps if someone is stuck with this issue